# Complex procedure to adjust data continously

Tags: oracle, triggers, self-join

I solved this in SQL Server with a trigger. Now I face it on Oracle.

I have a big set of data that periodically increases with new items.
The item has these fundamental columns:

- `ID string` identifier (not null)
- `DATETIME` (not null)
- optional (eventually null, always null for type 1) `DATETIME_EMIS` emission datetame equal to the `DATETIME` of the corresponding emission item
- `type` (0 or 1)
- `value` (only if type 1)

It is basically a logbook.

For example: An item with ID='FIREALARM' and datetime='2023-02-12 12:02' has closing like this:

```
ID='FIREALARM' in datetime='2023-02-12 15:11', emission datetime='2023-02-12 12:02' (equal to the emission item).
```

What I need is to obtain a final item in the destination table like this:

```
ID='FIREALARM' in DATETIME_BEGIN ='2023-02-12 12:02', DATETIME_END ='2023-02-12 15:11'
```

Not all the items have the closing datetime (the ones of Type=1 instead 0), in this case the next item should be use to close the previous one (with the problem of finding it). For example:

Item1:

```
ID='DEVICESTATUS', datetime='2023-02-12 22:11', Value='Broken' ;
```

Item2:

```
ID='DEVICESTATUS', datetime='2023-02-12 22:14', Value='Running'
```

Should result in

```
ID='DEVICESTATUS', DATETIME_BEGIN ='2023-02-12 22:11',DATETIME_END ='2023-02-12 22:14', Value='Broken'
```

The final data should be extracted by a select query as faster as possible.

The process of the elaboration should be independent from the order of inserting.

In SQL Server, I created a trigger with several operations which involve a temporary table, some queries on the inserted set and the entire destination table, so a complex procedure that is not worth to be shown to understand the problem.

Now I discovered that Oracle has some limitations and is not easy to port the trigger on it. For example is not easy to use a temporary table in the same way, and the operation are for each row.

I am asking what could be a good strategy in Oracle to elaborate the data in the final form considering that the set increase continuously and the open and the closure items must be reduce to a single item. I am not asking for a solution of the problem, I am trying to understand what could be the instrument in Oracle useful to achieve a complex elaboration like this. Thanks.

Comment: It would be much easier if you include the sample data as `CREATE TABLE`/`INSERT` statements that we can copy-paste and execute and if you focused the post on the logic that you want to implement (rather than the XY-problem of re-implementing the SQL server solution in a different language). Also, you mention `DATETIME_EMIS` and `TYPE` but neither appear in your sample data and do not appear to be relevant to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   destination
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY datetime
  MEASURES
    FIRST(datetime) AS datetime_begin,
    LAST(datetime)  AS datetime_end,
    FIRST(value)    AS value
  PATTERN ( ^ any_row+ $ )
  DEFINE
    any_row AS 1 = 1
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE destination (id, datetime, value) AS
SELECT 'DEVICESTATUS', DATE '2023-02-12' + INTERVAL '22:11' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'Broken'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEVICESTATUS', DATE '2023-02-12' + INTERVAL '22:14' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'Running' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DATETIME_BEGIN | DATETIME_END | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEVICESTATUS | 2023-02-12 22:11:00 | 2023-02-12 22:14:00 | Broken |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/idhk4s4f)